# How to pass slice formula when creating ADF from C#

Tags: azure-data-factory

The code below generates this error

> ADWStoredProcActivity failed: Error converting data type nvarchar to date.

Code:

```
Dictionary<string, StoredProcedureParameter> parameters
                       = new Dictionary<string, StoredProcedureParameter>() {
                         { "DateToImportFor", new StoredProcedureParameter("$$Text.Format('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}', SliceStart)","string") }
                        };
var pipelineName = "Azure Stored Procedure Pipeline";

PipelineResource pipeline = new PipelineResource
            {
                Activities = new List<Activity>
                    {
                        new SqlServerStoredProcedureActivity
                        {
                            Name="ADWStoredProcActivity",
                            LinkedServiceName =  new LinkedServiceReference(AzureDWLinkedServiceName),
                            StoredProcedureName = "DailyImport",
                            StoredProcedureParameters = parameters
                        }
                    }
            };

client.Pipelines.CreateOrUpdate(resourceGroup, dataFactoryName, pipelineName, pipeline);
Console.WriteLine(SafeJsonConvert.SerializeObject(pipeline, client.SerializationSettings));
```

When I substitute the formula with literal value it works.

I am creating ADF with a stored procedure activity via code.